# "Veni, vidi, vici" but in the plural form

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, plural

"I came saw and won" but to the plural form of "we came, we saw, we won".
My Latin is beyond rusty.
What would you recommend as the proper form?

Gratias tibi!

Answer (score 23):

The plural form would be simply:

> Venimus, vidimus, vicimus.

This is the perfect tense, so all verbs have the same endings and the nice parallel remains.